# Why I can't find the "temporary file" which is uploaded by php file upload function in my localhost?

Tags: php

Well, I am checking where is the temporary file is uploaded using the php with following code :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){    
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_FILES);
}
```

It's return

```
Array
(
[file] => Array
    (
        [name] => button.jpg
        [type] => image/jpeg
        [tmp_name] => D:\Softwares Installed\xampp\tmp\phpB994.tmp
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 58448
    )

)
```

Now after that I checked the directory : D:\Softwares Installed\xampp\tmp\phpB994.tmp, but can't find the file ? why I can't find it ?

**Update:**

With following code I am checking if file type is jpg, jpeg, png or gif format.

```
$file_type =  $_FILES['file']['type'];
```

If file has correct type then following code should not return any error but it's showing error. I mean `echo` message

```
elseif( ($file_type !== "image/jpg") || ($file_type !== "image/gif") || ($file_type !== "image/jpeg") || ($file_type !== "image/jpeg")  ){
    echo 'file type not allowed';
}
```

But when I use this it's working fine:

```
elseif( ($file_type !== "image/jpg") && ($file_type !== "image/gif") && ($file_type !== "image/jpeg") && ($file_type !== "image/jpeg")  ){
    echo 'file type not allowed';
}
```

Comment: Why not use `move_uploaded_file()` ?

Comment: @Jan I already checked with move_uploaded_file(). It's successfully uploaded in my selected directory but I want to know where is temporary file BEFORE moved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The temporary  will be deleted from the temporary directory at the end of the request if it has not been moved away or renamed.

So you can move those file before completing script

***Good Read*** : [**POST method uploads ¶**](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Comment: is there any way to see the temporary file ?

Comment: @shibbirahmed yes rename it or move from other place

Comment: If i move I know I can see it but actually I want to see the phpB994.tmp file.

Comment: @shibbirahmed no you can not see it

Comment: Thanks Ok I understand. Can you please check my update questions ?

Comment: @shibbirahmed well its different question, just waite for bit ill show you how to validate image